# Calculation of a double integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^2 \sqrt{\left|y-x^2\right|} \,dx \,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^2 \sqrt{\left|y-x^2\right|} \,dx \,dy.
$$
I tried to go first with $y$  which seems the easier of the two, but then the integral with respect to $x$ becomes quite complex.

On the other hand, starting with $x$ it is cumbersome and further the integral with respect to $y$  is more complex than the first method...

Is there a simple way  to do it??

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your method, so it is not possible for me to compare my method and yours' method and decide which is simpler.

Given integral: $$I = \int^{1}_{-1} \int^2_0 \sqrt{|{y-x^2}|} dx dy $$
Let $ f(x,y) = \sqrt{|y-x^2|} $

Here, you have to careful for the values inside $(|.|)$. It should be obvious that for $y \in (-1,0) $ ,$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{| -|y| -x^2 |} =  \sqrt{| |y| + x^2 |} $$

And for $ y \in (0,1)$, there are two cases:

- Case 1: If $ x < \sqrt{y}$, for that $f(x,y) = \sqrt{y-x^2} $
- Case 2: If $ x \ge \sqrt{y}$, for that $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 -y} $

So,$$I =  \int^0_{-1} \int^2_0 \sqrt{ |y| + x^2} + \int^1_0 \int^{\sqrt{y}}_0 \sqrt{y-x^2} dx dy + \int^1_0 \int_{\sqrt{y}}^2 \sqrt{x^2-y} dx dy$$ 
As the first integral is insenstive to the values of variable $y$, integral $I$ can be written as $$ =  \int^1_{0} \int^2_0 \sqrt{ y + x^2} + \int^1_0 \int^{\sqrt{y}}_0 \sqrt{y-x^2} dx dy + \int^1_0 \int_{\sqrt{y}}^2 \sqrt{x^2-y} dx dy$$

Now, all the integrals are of standard form, they can be solved easily, and I leave you that as an exercise.

Comment: Limits are x(-1, 1)  and y(0, 2)  but i get it.. There is not a simple way. It is a cumbersome integral

Comment: Integratation can be easily performed for x, which function in particular you are facing problem when integrating with respect to dy?

Comment: Possibly $y \ln(\sqrt{y + c_1} + c_2) $ ?